# Wikidata entries that can't be retrieved by SPARQL queries?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am trying to run a simple query, looking up an item by its English label. For some reason, some entries are not showing. Most are fine, but some aren't. I can't pinpoint why.

An example: `oyster bed`. Here is the entry: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q65953972

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE {  
        ?item ?label 'oyster bed'@en.  
        ?article schema:about ?item .
        ?article schema:inLanguage 'en' .
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'en'. }
  }
```

and I get nothing.

The same query with `oyster` yields an expected result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're ignoring the case that there is no article about the entity: `select * {
 ?item rdfs:label "oyster bed"@en .
    optional {?article schema:about ?item .
        ?article schema:inLanguage 'en' .
    }
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'en'. }
  }`

Comment: So simple! Thank you, @UninformedUser. Indeed it worked! If you write it as a reply, I will upvote it. If not, I'll just post my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hat tip of @UninformedUser helped.

As a SPARQL newbie, I did not realise the `?article` was an implicit JOIN.

```sql
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE {  
        ?item ?label 'oyster bed'@en.  
        OPTIONAL { ?article schema:about ?item .
        ?article schema:inLanguage 'en' . }
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'en'. }
  }
```

is to be used if the article is required, but if there is no real need, the query can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE {  
        ?item ?label 'oyster bed'@en.  
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language 'en'. }
  }
```